# when trying to chaincode instantiate,error

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

i'm studying the fabric ca operations guide document.
But when i trying to instantiate the chaincode , error occured.
Instantiate command:

```
peer chaincode instantiate -C mychannel -n mycc -v 1.0 -c '{"Args":["init","a","100","b","200"]}' -o orderer1-org0:7050 --tls --cafile /tmp/hyperledger/org2/peer1/tls-msp/tlscacerts/tls-0-0-0-0-7052.pem
```

error message :

```
2020-02-21 04:13:57.176 UTC [grpc] switchBalancer -> DEBU 045 ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"
2020-02-21 04:13:57.176 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 046 pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc0003c3d70, CONNECTING
2020-02-21 04:13:57.179 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 047 pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc0003c3d70, READY
2020-02-21 04:13:57.179 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 048 Using default escc
2020-02-21 04:13:57.179 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 049 Using default vscc
2020-02-21 04:13:57.180 UTC [msp.identity] Sign -> DEBU 04a Sign: plaintext: 0AD8080A6608031A0B0885B2BDF20510...30300A000A04657363630A0476736363 
2020-02-21 04:13:57.180 UTC [msp.identity] Sign -> DEBU 04b Sign: digest: 5480C64F725F648C381B7820B6EA079636CA6C6A8C1D51319B30116653888FF1 
Error: could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg transaction returned with failure: Attribute 'abac.init' was not found
```

Can anyone explain to me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your `Init` function is being called when instantiating, but it is failing.

I suppose your chaincode is https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.4/chaincode/abac/go/abac.go. The fact is that the requestor certificate should have the attribute "abac.init" to true, but yours haven't. That's defined during the Fabric CA registration and included in your enrolled certificate.

Comment: yes. In document, it only add the attribute 'abac.init=true' when registering orderer-admin from org0-ca. Should i add the attribute org1's admin and org2's admin? The document is https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/operations_guide.html

Comment: You need it in whatever user you are using to run the instantiation.

Comment: Does the user that you say means all? For example, peer, admin, orderer ??

Comment: It depends on your policies, but normally an admin from any organization belonging to the channel is needed to instantiate the chaincode on the channel. So register that admin in the required way, enroll its certificate and use that admin to instantiate the chaincode.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll try that. Have a nice day.